What electronic component is this, marked "11GG"
A 10-pin chip with a screen print of 11GG. May be a Hall sensor, but I can't find any information about this chip. At present, I only know the size of this IC 3.2*2.85 mm. There are magnets near this chip. This IC is supposed to be a magnetic sensor.The picture of the chip is as follows:



well, where was this mounted?

@Marcus Müller,used on Japanese digital cameras

where on that camera? There's got to be a reason why it was mounted alone, at the end of a PCB

Only know to control the anti-shake group, a group needs two controls

I think it's a magnetic Hall sensor

Please add the info about camera and which part it's a component of to your question!

I haven't been able to find this DFN3x3-10 device but as other have mentioned, without knowing where exactly has come from, there's no context. You mentioned that you believe it's a hall effect sensor but there's nothing to prove that. It could be a motor driver that can automatically just the lens position of the camera that you speak of when it autofocuses.

This IC is an anti-shake board line, used on Canon digital cameras
